# issue with setwd and mapped network drive on Azure VM machine (windows)

Tags: r

I am getting:

```
Error in setwd("E:/Data/bla") : cannot change working directory
```

when I run:

```
setwd("E:/Data/bla")
```

I have a network drive:

```
\\blabla\c$
```

mapped to my E drive on this Azure VM machine. I can access data via explorer no problem.

Why do I get the error and what is a solution? Strangely, I do not get this error on any on prem machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445241/application-cannot-access-mapped-drive) using, in my case:

```
net use E: \\blabla\c$
```

solves the issue. I leave this here as it may help others.